# New version .NET 6 is not work without get set

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

My old project is using .NET Core 2.2 and I need to migrate it to .NET 6.

The previous developer added some classes something like this:

```
public class ClassName
{
    public int code;
    public string message;
}
```

And API controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetTotal")]
    public List<ClassName> GetTotal(DateTime dtCur)
    {
        List<ClassName> l = new List<ClassName>();

        ClassName n = new ClassName()
        {
                code = -99,
                message = "invalid session"
        };

        l.Add(n);

        return l;
    }
```

It worked on .NET Core 2.2, but on .NET 6, it always returns an empty array from ajax or Postman.

To get it done in .NET 6, I must fix class like this:

```
public class ClassName
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

But the problem is all classes in old projects they did not add `{ get; set; }` to any classes, this mean I must fix all them.

Is there any way to fix it quickly, or someone can explain why in .NET 6 return empty in this case?

Comment: By default, field are not serialized to JSON.
You could try adding something like this to support field serialization:
var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions { IncludeFields = true }

Comment: @monstertjie_za by default fields are serializable. Having Property Setters and Getter is a good practice and perhaps required now with the move to `using System.Text.Json` See this, you can create classes like OP shows and they will serialize, there must be something else wrong. OP ae you using the correct type  `JsonSerializer.Serialize<IsThisCorrectType>(weatherForecast);` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario, you can enable field serialization globally in `Program.cs` as:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;    
});
```

Comment: Then you'd need to decorate each Member variable with a `[JsonInclude]`, good guess though!

Comment: Hi @JeremyThompson, Just choose one of the two ways. Global settings in Program.cs or decorate the `[JsonInclude]` for each property. And for op's scenario, global setting is a better way.